# Android kotlin - sort mutable list by value

Tags: android, kotlin

This is the list:

```
[Videos(id=5, yt_id=yRPUkDjwr1A, title=test5, likes=0, kat=animals), Videos(id=4, yt_id=yRPUkDjwr1A, title=test4, likes=1, kat=pranks), Videos(id=3, yt_id=WkyUU9ZDUto, title=test3, likes=1, kat=pranks), Videos(id=2, yt_id=B_X9OQqtduE, title=test2, likes=0, kat=animals), Videos(id=1, yt_id=ywaKlGNiv80, title=test1, likes=0, kat=animals)]
```

How can I sort it by `likes` desc?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [sortByDescending](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sort-by-descending.html):

```
videos.sortByDescending { it.likes }
```

I think it is self explanatory.
If you want to assign the sorted result to another list use [sortedByDescending](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-by-descending.html):

```
val sortedList = videos.sortedByDescending { it.likes }
```

The result list's inferred type is `List<Videos>`, but if you want a `MutableList`:

```
val sortedList = videos.sortedByDescending { it.likes }.toMutableList()
```

Comment: I tried: val finalvids = vids.sortByDescending { it.likes } but now finalvids is type "unit" and I can't use it as I would use vids, how to fix this?

Comment: Oh I see I don't need to put it in new val but still, can I do it somehow? Because I still need the old version too

Comment: `sortedByDescending` does not change the original list.

Comment: Change to `val sortedList = videos.sortedByDescending { it.likes }.toMutableList()`